# Moving object Opengl Es 2.0

Tags: opengl-es

I am a bit confused about that I need to move my basic square .Should i use my translate matrix or just change the object vertexes. Which one is accurate ?.

I use vertex shader 
gl_Position =   myPMVMatrix * a_vertex;

and also i use VBO

Comment: As you're new here, be sure to inform yourself about the accept and up-vote features.

Answer (score 3):

From an accuracy point of view both methods are about equally good.

From a performance point of view, it's about minimizing bottlenecks:
For a single square you are probably not able to measure any differences, but when you think about 1 million squares (or triangles), thinks get a little more complicated:

If all of your triangles change position relative to each other, you are probably better off with changing the vbo, because you can push the data directly to the graphics card's memory, instead of having a million OpenGl calls (which are very slow).

If all your triangles stay at the same position relative to each other (like it is the case in a normal 3d-model) you should just change the transformation matrix. In this case you don't have to push the data again onto the gfx-memory, and you only have one function-call, and you are transfering only a few bytes of data to the gfx-memory.

Depending on your application it may be a good choice to devide your triangles into different categories and update them apropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Don't move objects by changing all of the vertices! What about a complex model with thousands of vertices? Even if it's a simple square, don't evolve such bad practice. That's exactly what transformation matrices are for. You are already using a transformation matrix in your shader code. From the naming I assume it's a premultiplied model-view-projection matrix. So it consists of the model matrix positioning the object in world space (here's where your translation usually should go into), the view matrix positioning the world in eye/camera space (sometimes model and view matrix are combined into a single modelview matrix, like in fixed function GL) and the projection matrix doing any kind of perspective projection and/or transformation to the clipping volume, all three multiplied together as P * V * M. If there are still some questions on these transformation matrices and their use, consult some literature on 3d transformations or just your favourite OpenGL tutorial.